# What's a __varmap__ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've been using memprof on a script in Ruby 1.8.7, and the most common thing that's created is a `__varmap__`. What is a varmap?

Comment: A quick review of the C source suggests that varmaps are symbol tables of a sort, they appear to be used to track variables in methods and blocks so every block and method call would need a varmap. Maybe I'll take a shot at a real answer later, no time right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think varmap refers to T_VARMAP which is an in-block variable container: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/141449 .  When memprof encounters a T_VARMAP it prints out `__varmap__` : https://github.com/ice799/memprof/blob/master/ext/memprof.c